# Family of Lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Problem:

> Consider a family of straight lines $(x+y)+\lambda(2x-y+1)=0$. Find the equation of the straight line belonging to this family which is farthest from $(1,-3)$.

$$$$

Any help with this problem would be really appreciated!

Comment: use Lagrange's multiplier method: (x-1)^2+(y+3)^2 versus the given equation. It works.

Comment: I have a solution that doesn't require finding $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it geometrically. Since the family of lines all pass through $I\left(-\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}\right)$, the largest distance from any point $A$ to a line passing through $I$ will be the length $IA$. Therefore, the problem becomes:

> Find the equation of the line containing $I\left(-\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}\right)$ and perpendicular to $IA$ where $A(1,-3)$.

**Solution**

The slope of the line passing through $IA$ is

> $$ m_{IA} = \frac{-3 - \frac{1}{3}}{1 - (-\frac{1}{3})} = -\frac{5}{2} $$

You want the slope of the line perpendicular to this, which is

> $$m_{\lambda} = -\frac{1}{m_{IA}}=\frac{2}{5}$$

Combined with the known point, the equation is

> $$y = \frac{2}{5}x + \frac{7}{15}$$

**Edit: Reasoning for perpendicularity**

Let $H$ be the intersection of a perpendicular line drawn from $A$. We have $AH$ is the distance from $A$ to the line.

Suppose $IA$ makes an angle $\theta$ with the line in question, it follows that $AH = IA\sin\theta \le IA$. Thus $AH = IA$ when $\theta = 90^\circ$ or $H \equiv I$

Comment: +1. That's the approach I was going to post. :)  To be more explicit with your first claim: For a particular line through $I$, if $P$ is the closest point on that line to $A$, then $\angle IPA$ is a right angle. By [Thales Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem), all such points $P$ lie on the circle with diameter $\overline{IA}$. Consequently, $I$ itself is the farthest of these points from $A$, ... and the rest of your argument goes from there.

Comment: or you can just say that since $IA$ is the hypotenuse, $IP \le IA$, so $IP$ is largest when $P \equiv I$

Comment: True enough. I just really like observing that the points $P$ lie on a circle. :)

Comment: @BetterWorld The slope makes the equation $y = \frac{2}{5}x + c$. Plug in the known point $x = -\frac{1}{3}, y = {1}{3}$ gives you the value of $c$

Answer (score 0):

We can write the equation as $\displaystyle (2\lambda+1)x+(1-\lambda)y+\lambda+1 =0$

Now Perpendicular Distance of Line from Point $\bf{P(1,-3)}$ is $ = PQ=\displaystyle \left|\frac{2\lambda+1+3\lambda-3+\lambda+1}{\sqrt{(2\lambda+1)^2+(1-\lambda)^2}}\right|$

Now $\displaystyle PQ = \left|\frac{6\lambda-1}{\sqrt{5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2}}\right|\;,$ Then we have to $\bf{Maximize}$ the value of $$\displaystyle \frac{6\lambda-1}{\sqrt{5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2}}$$

Now Let $$\displaystyle f(\lambda) = \frac{(6\lambda-1)^2}{5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2}$$.(Bcz If $f(\lambda)$ is $\bf{Max.}\;,$ Then $\left[f(\lambda)\right]^2$ is $\bf{Max.}$)

Now Let $$\displaystyle z = \frac{36\lambda^2+1-12\lambda}{5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2}\Rightarrow 5\lambda^2\cdot z+2\lambda \cdot z+2z = 36\lambda^2-12\lambda+1$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \left(5z-36\right)\lambda^2+2(z+6)\lambda+(2z-1) =0\;,$$ For real roots, Then $\bf{Discriminant\geq 0}$

So $$\displaystyle 4\left(z+6\right)^2-4\cdot (5z-36)\cdot (2z-1)\geq 0$$

So $(z+6)^2-(5z-36)\cdot (2z-1)\geq 0$

So $$\displaystyle z^2+36+12z-10z^2+77z-36\geq 0$$

So $$\displaystyle -9z^2+89z\geq 0\Rightarrow 9z^2-89z\leq 0$$

So we get $$\displaystyle z\leq \frac{89}{9}$$

So $$\displaystyle \bf{Max.(z) = \frac{89}{9}}$$

Now Put $\displaystyle z = \frac{89}{9}$ in $$\displaystyle z = \frac{(6\lambda-1)^2}{5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2}\;,$$ We Get $\displaystyle \lambda = -\frac{13}{11}$

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the distance from a point $(x_1,y_1)$ to a line $ax+by+c=0$ is given by:$\dfrac{ax_1+by_1+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, then maybe you could rewrite that formula for the point $\left(1,-3\right)$ and the line $(x+y)+\lambda(2x-y+1)=0$ ?

After that you will just need to find the $\lambda$ for which this formula is maximal. Then the farthest line is described by that value of $\lambda$.

Comment: As juantheron stated, you want to maximise $\left|\frac{6\lambda-1}{\sqrt{5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2}}\right|$. Since it is positive, it is maximal iff its square is maximal. Now you have to maximize $\frac{(6\lambda-1)^2}{5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2}$. In order to do so you may try to differentiate this, and find the points for which the derivative is $0$. The maximum is reached at one of those points, so you just have to test which one gives the highest value.

Comment: Please note that this reasoning is correct only if the formula's maxima isn't reached at $\pm \infty$, which is the case here.

Comment: If I have a function $f: R->R^{+}$, what I'm saying is that, for $x_0 \in R$, $\max f = f(x_0) \iff max f²=(f(x_0))²$. Such a result is true because the square and the square root functions are increasing in $R^{+}$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the equation of straight lines $$x+y+\lambda(2x-y+1)=0$$  $$(2\lambda +1)x+(1-\lambda)y+\lambda=0$$

Now, the distance say $D$ of the above line from the given point $(1, -3)$ is given as follows $$D=\left|\frac{(2\lambda +1)(1)+(1-\lambda)(-3)+\lambda}{\sqrt{(2\lambda +1)^2+(1-\lambda )^2}}\right|$$

$$=\left|\frac{(2\lambda +1)(1)+(1-\lambda)(-3)+\lambda}{\sqrt{(2\lambda +1)^2+(1-\lambda )^2}}\right|$$
$$=\left|\frac{6\lambda-2}{5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2}\right|$$
Now, considering the following function: $f(\lambda)=\frac{6\lambda-2}{5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2}$

$$\frac{df(\lambda)}{d\lambda}=\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left(\frac{6\lambda-2}{5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2}\right)$$ $$=\frac{(5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2)(6)-(6\lambda-2)(10\lambda+2)}{(5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2)^2}$$
$$=\frac{-30\lambda^2+20\lambda+16}{(5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2)^2}$$

Now, for maximum value of $D$ we have $$\frac{df(\lambda)}{d\lambda}=0$$

$$\frac{-30\lambda^2+20\lambda+16}{(5\lambda^2+2\lambda+2)^2}=0$$

$$15\lambda^2-10\lambda-8=0$$ $$\lambda=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{145}}{15}$$$$\iff \lambda =\frac{5+\sqrt{145}}{15}\ \vee\ \lambda=\frac{5-\sqrt{145}}{15}$$

Now, find $\frac{d^2f(\lambda)}{d\lambda^2}$ & substitute these values of $\lambda $ individually in $\frac{d^2f(\lambda)}{d\lambda^2}$ then you will find that for $\lambda=\frac{5+\sqrt{145}}{15}$,   $\frac{d^2f(\lambda)}{d\lambda^2}<0$

Thus, the function $f(\lambda)$ will be maximum & hence the distance $D$ of the given point from the line will be maximum at $\lambda=\frac{5+\sqrt{145}}{15}$
Now, substituting this value   of $\lambda $ in the given equation of family of straight lines we get the equation of the straight line farthest from the given point $(1, -3)$
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{x+y+\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{145}}{15}\right)(2x-y-1)=0}}$$